# Viewing org unit attributes in pivot table analysis in DHIS2

Tags: dhis2

How can I generate the attributes I defined and assigned to Organisation units on pivot table report. Like if I assign an attribute say Old Health Facility, Old health facility.

Answer (score 1):

You can classify organisation units and later do analysis based on the classification through *Organisation unit group sets*.

Go to the organisation units module. According to your example:

1. Create organisation unit groups for each type of health facility you need, e.g. "Dispensary", "Clinic", "Facility". Make sure that you select the appropriate organisation units as members of each group.
2. Create an organisation unit group set called "Facility type" with all the new groups as members.
3. You need to re-generate the analytics tables for this to take effect in analytics.

You can now go to the analytics apps (pivot table, data visualizer, GIS) and do analysis according to those new dimensions (classifications). You can see the "Facility type" dimension being available in the left-hand menu.